# connect to PostgreSQL 9.5 database from Visual Studio 2015 via Npgsql

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, postgresql, database-connection, npgsql

I installed NpgsqlDdexProvider-3.1.0, through NuGet added to the project packages Npgsql v.3.0.5, EntityFramework5.Npgsql v.3.0.5, EntityFramework v.5.0.0. I try to add connection to database via Server Explorer and get error:

> Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider

My data provider: .Net Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL (Npgsql Ddex Provider)

My connection string:

`Host=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=1;Database=postgres;`

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add provider's dll to GAC and assemble of your IDE.